# c# Parsing json to object

Tags: c#

I need some help to parse the json rest from IsThereASale API to a c# object but I got stuck because of the json layout:

https://del.dog/orfelefane.json

What I need here is the info from the data array.

Here is how i get the json response:

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://api.isthereanydeal.com/");
 client.UseNewtonsoftJson();

 var request = new RestRequest("https://api.isthereanydeal.com/v01/deals/list/?key=" + Config.apiKey + "&sort=time");
 var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response.Content);
```

As you can notice above I've tried to convert it to a dictionary, but with no success.

Comment: Could you add also a sample of json returned by the API please?

Comment: @Martin Staufcik check the link I've posted. I mean this https://del.dog/orfelefane.json

Comment: Well, it is not a dictionary, it is a complex object type.

Comment: I don't see your request in action... However, the `DeserializeObject` should accept a class or an interface similar to that response you're getting from that api instead of a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [online converter](https://app.quicktype.io?share=fAdQkSPTy1XUfgronpod) for this

```
public partial class Orfelefane
{
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class Data
{
    public long Count { get; set; }
    public List<List> List { get; set; }
    public DataUrls Urls { get; set; }
}

public partial class List
{
    public string Plain { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double PriceNew { get; set; }
    public double PriceOld { get; set; }
    public long PriceCut { get; set; }
    public long Added { get; set; }
    public long? Expiry { get; set; }
    public Shop Shop { get; set; }
    public List<Drm> Drm { get; set; }
    public ListUrls Urls { get; set; }
}

public partial class Shop
{
    public Id Id { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class ListUrls
{
    public Uri Buy { get; set; }
    public Uri Game { get; set; }
}

public partial class DataUrls
{
    public Uri Deals { get; set; }
}

public partial class Meta
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

public enum Drm { DrmFree, Steam };

public enum Id { Bundlestars, Gog, Itchio, Steam };

public enum Name { Fanatical, Gog, ItchIo, Steam };
```

lastly

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Orfelefane>(response.Content);
```

**EDIT:**

If your json is not stronglytyped, I suggest you to use

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
```

If only the specific part of your json is not static then you can replace that part with `dynamic`

let say that the content of the `List` is dynamic inside data, then change

```
public partial class Data
{
    public long Count { get; set; }
    public List<List> List { get; set; }
    public DataUrls Urls { get; set; }
}
```

to

```
public partial class Data
{
    public long Count { get; set; }
    //OR public dynamic List {get; set;}
    public List<dynamic> List { get; set; } 
    public DataUrls Urls { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But something I noticed is that the json returned doesn't always have the same values: ArgumentException: Must specify valid information for parsing in the string.

Comment: Ok that is what you need to point out in your post in the first place :) If you know which parts of the json changes, you can replace that type with dynamic. Check my edit

Comment: Ok thanks. What changed are the arrays representing the shop:

Comment: public enum Id { Dlgamer };

    public enum Name { DlGamer };
Here are the new values. You can notice the change from the json I had. They are changed based on the shop available for the respectie game on sale

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out in the end :)